# How to check if an IntentService was started

Tags: android, intentservice

I'd like to get to know if an Activity successfully started an `IntentService`.

As it's possible to bind an `IntentService` via `bindService()` to keep it running, perhaps an approach would be to check if invoking `startService(intent)` results in a call of `onStartCommand(..)` or `onHandleIntent(..)` in the service object.

But how can I check that in the Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to get to know if an Activity successfully started an IntentService.

If you don't get an exception in either the activity or the service when you call `startService()`, then the `IntentService` was started.

> As it's possible to bind an IntentService via bindService() to keep it running

Why?

Comment: I just want to make sure that a service was started. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here's the method I use to check if my service is running. The Sercive class is DroidUptimeService.

```
private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> serviceList = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (serviceList.size() <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++) {
        RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo = serviceList.get(i);
        ComponentName serviceName = serviceInfo.service;
        if (serviceName.getClassName().equals(DroidUptimeService.class.getName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but that's not what I'm searching for - I need to check if startService() is called, not if the service is actually running...

Comment: Hummm, they you have to have your Service broadcast and Intent to tell you that it was started. looks like the only option to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a flag when constructing the `PendingIntent`, if the returned value was `null`, your service is not started. The mentioned flag is `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourContext,YourService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =   PendingIntent.getService(yourContext,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

if (pendingIntent == null){
    return "service is not created yet";
} else {
    return "service is already running!";
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you started you service using a PendingIntent, with an AlarmManager for example, the doc for that FLAG states that: Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent does not already exist, then simply return null instead of creating it. For long running services will not work

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I use to check if my service is running:

```
  public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return service.started;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```