# How to check if a service is already running or not in android?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

In my project I am starting a service when a button is clicked.
But I don't want to start that service again when that button is clicked unless the previous one is already stopped. So I need to check first whether the service is running or not. I used the following method

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But its not working for me, it doesnt give any exception but always returns false. what should I do now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running

Comment: I took that method from your link before, but its not working

Comment: If you debug through the code, is your service being picked up in the `for` loop? ie Is your service actually being found by `manager.getRunningServices()`?

Comment: change this "com.example.MyService" to your package.

Comment: This didn't work for my Intent Service, the below solution worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060793/how-to-check-if-an-intentservice-was-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason why your service is not listed in running services is the way you start your service. The following proposal is the [same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/android-check-if-a-service-is-running) you took your method from.

```
You MUST call startService for your service to be properly registered and
passing BIND_AUTO_CREATE will not suffice.
```

Like the following:

```
Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this,ServiceTask.class);
startService(bindIntent);
bindService(bindIntent,mConnection,0);
```

Try this and see if it works for you too.

Comment: Hi, but what is the purpose of mConnection?

Answer (score 0):

Your method return false because after stop, process is destroyed by system if there are no any clients bound to service.